# providedRuntime `spring-boot-starter-undertow` in `build.gradle` but `:bootRun` still using Tomcat instead of undertow

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have just initialised a new Spring Boot application and my `build.gradle` has the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

When I run `./gradlew bootRun`, it is using Tomcat.  I understand `starter-web` includes Tomcat, but isn't `providedRuntime` there to override that?

How do I actually use undertow to run my Spring controllers?

EDIT:

I just realised my `ServletInitializer.java` looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AccountServiceApplication.class);
    }

}
```

This tells me it is initialising a servlet, which I assumed is `undertow` based on the dependencies, but was I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude tomcat from the build:

```
dependencies {
  implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
      exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
  providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Comment: I tried that before, but actually had a typo in the excluded tomcat module name ... Works now, thanks!